# SQL-select previous day and exclude today

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to include all the records that was registered yesterday but exclude any records that has been registered today. I am not sure if this query is giving me correct numer of records. Please help

```
select id, lastmodifieddate  from stu_tbl
where last_modified_date > DATEADD(d, - 1, GETDATE())) 
and _last_modified_date <>  GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id, last_modifieddate  from stu_tbl
where last_modified_date >= DATEADD(d, -1, cast(GETDATE() as date)) 
  and last_modified_date < cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the last line 'and last_modified_date <cast (getdate()as date' isn't making any difference at all. I can include or exclude that, I get same no of records. Am I missing something here, help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL Server 2008+ solution:

```
select id, lastmodifieddate  
from stu_tbl
where last_modified_date >= cast(dateadd(day, -1, GetDate()) as Date)
and last_modified_date < cast(GetDate() as Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @Dfrom  datetime
declare @Dto    datetime
declare @Dyesterday datetime

--Get date before current date
set @Dyesterday = dateadd(day, -1, getdate())

--Set date from to 12am
set @Dfrom = CONVERT(varchar(20), @Dyesterday, 101)

--set date to to 11:59:59PM
set @Dto = CONVERT(varchar(20), @Dyesterday, 101) + ' 23:59:59'

--if date and time is required
select  id, lastmodifieddate
from    stu_tbl
where   last_modified_date between @Dfrom and @Dto
```

OR

```
--if date only and time is not required
select  id, lastmodifieddate
from    stu_tbl
where   last_modified_date = @Dfrom
```